# How do I change button text automatically with a segment change

Tags: swift, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to create a log in screen for users, and so when they are on the "log in" segment of the segmented control, I want it to display "log in" on my button. However when the user switches to the "Sign in" segment I want the button to display "sign in" and not "log in". The only way I have gotten it to display "sign in" so far is by making the user click the button, and using `actionButton.setTitle("sign in", for: .normal)` to change the text, but I want it to happen automatically as soon as the user switches segment. Does anyone know how to do this?

[This is what my view controller for the sign up page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WRA5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    segment.addTarget(self, action: #selector(valueDidChange(segment:)), for: .valueChanged)
}

func valueDidChange(segment: UISegmentControl) {
    switch segment.selectedIndex {
    case 0:
        actionButton.setTitle("log in", for: .normal)
    default:
        actionButton.setTitle("sign in", for: .normal)
    }
}
```